# How to find an irreducible polynomial over a finite field with a primitive root (and low hamming weight)

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, primitive-roots

I found [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166323/roots-of-an-irreducible-polynomial-in-a-finite-field) that a polynomial in $F[x]$ with $|F| =q $ with degree $n$ will have its roots in $K$ of order $q^n$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655433/irreducible-polynomials-and-primitive-elements-over-a-finite-field), I found that either all the roots are primitive or none of them are.

I am looking for a way to build efficiently a polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n$ which roots are of multiplicative order $p^n -1$ in $K$.

If such algorithm exists, is there a way to find among all possible $P_n$, the one(s) with the smallest hamming weight ? (fewest non-zero coefficients)

Any help is welcome

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I believe this is a difficult problem in general. A lot of work has gone towards studying primitive trinomials over $\Bbb{F}_2$, but this has never been my specialty, so I cannot say much at all. IIRC a few cases with $n<30$ are known, where no primitive trinomials exist. May be it is even known that those fizzle out? A larger $p$ gives more elbow room.

Comment: Search [1](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ezivkovm/publications/primpol1.pdf), [2](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1994-62-205/S0025-5718-1994-1201073-4/S0025-5718-1994-1201073-4.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen, that helped a lot !

Comment: The first post does not say the order of roots have order $q^n$. The multiplicative order of roots of degree $n$ polynomial cannot exceed $q^n -1$.